# Como quebrar uma coluna em novas colunas no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu não sei como fazer essa pergunta, mas vou tentar descrever meu caso.

Eu tenho um DataFrame com os dados dessa forma:

| Produto | Valor | Tipo do valor | Ano |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21,5 | Preço | 21 |
| A | 5 | Volume | 21 |
| B | 55,3 | Preço | 21 |
| B | 10 | Volume | 21 |
| C | 70,0 | Preço | 21 |
| D | 37,5 | Preço | 21 |
| D | 7,7 | Volume | 21 |

Eu quero chegar a uma base como esta:

| Produto | Preço | Volume | Ano |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21,5 | 5 | 21 |
| B | 55,3 | 10 | 21 |
| c | 70,0 | - | 21 |
| D | 37,0 | 7,7 | 21 |

Pensei que a função unstack poderia fazer isso, mas não consegui manter as outras colunas (como Ano)

A solução que pensei foi bem complexa.

```
container = []
for label, _df in df.groupby(['Ano','Produto']):
  _df.set_index('Tipo do Valor', inplace = True)
  container.append(pd.DataFrame({
                        "Produto": [label[1]],
                        "Preço":[_df.loc['Preço', 'Valor']],
                        "Volume": [_df.loc['Volume', 'Valor']],
                        "Ano":[label[0]]}))

df_new = pd.concat(container)
```

Porem essa solução dá erro na linha do produto C, por essa não possuir dados de volume.

Como posso chegar ao dataframe desejado de uma maneira que seja rápida? Pois a base real é bem grande

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que você queira.
Você deve usar a funçao .pivot() do pandas.

[Aqui documentação oficial do pandas sobre .pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Aqui o como deve ser:

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(index=['Produto','Ano'], 
               columns='Tipo do valor',
               values='Valor').reset_index()
```

Demonstração do código:

[image: demonstração do codigo]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor, prefira documentações ao usar citações.